Нужна ли фильтрация данных при добавлении в mysqli базу
все изменения в базе идут через prepared statement. Нужна ли фильтрация ввода на кавычки, слеши и т.д.?

Если prepared statement, то базе сделать инжекшн не должны.
Однако надо смотреть, как потом данные из базы попадают в хтмл.
Вот будет там 
Насколько я понимаю, нет, так как prepared statements нужны как раз для фильтрации.
